# SharpZipLib compression level between creating or updating a zip file

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I've got a couple of questions regarding the use of ShareZipLib.

1. I'm using 2 different methods to create a zip file and updating one which seems like overkill. Is there a better way?

**Create Zip File:**

```
   using (var zipFile = File.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.CreateNew))
   using (var outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(zipFile))
   {
    outputStream.Password = password;
    outputStream.SetLevel(compressionLevel); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression

    var buffer = new byte[4096];

    foreach (var file in filenames)
    {
        var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));

        entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

        outputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var sourceBytes = 0;
            do
            {
                sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
            } while (sourceBytes > 0);
        }
    }
    
    outputStream.Finish();
    outputStream.Close();
}
```

**Update ZipFile:**

```
using (var zipFile = File.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.Append))
using (var outputStream = new ZipFile(zipFile))
{
    outputStream.Password = password;
    outputStream.BeginUpdate();
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(filename));
        entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        outputStream.Add(entry);
    }
    outputStream.CommitUpdate();
}
```

2. I've tried using the File.Open(zipFilename, FileMode.Append) on the create method hoping I'd be able to append files to the zip file but it just overrides it. The only other way I found is the second method but as I said, it seems like an overkill. Hopefully, this can be simplified and this brings my second question/issue.

Why is the compression level set at the stream level, which makes sense to me by the way, when creating a new zip file but when you are updating a zip file, you have to set it at the file level.

Also when setting it at the stream level, it requires a number from 0 to 9.

```
outputStream.SetLevel(compressionLevel);
```

But when setting it at the file level on the update, it uses an enum:

[image]

Surely, you don't want to have different level of compression when adding and updating but 0 to 9 are not the values provided in the enum.

Thanks.

Comment: There are different version of the ZIP specification and some features are optional.  Not all tools implement the latest version or optional features.  A zip file is similar structure as a file system.  So you can only have one file in a directory with the same name. When you add a file to the zip you have a few choices and which choice you use will the time and size of the zip will be different.   One option would simply be to overwrite the original file.  The new file could be smaller or larger.

Comment: Another choice would be to add new file to end and then change the folder structure to point to new file instead of old.  Both the new and old would then be in the zip and it would be possible to get both new and old, but the size of the zip would always be larger.